# How to append to an existing Excel file?

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I am trying to append to an existing worksheet using the code below but it overwrites the existing data instead of appending.

```
string filePath = "c:\\CompareReport.xlsx";
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filePath);

using (var package = new ExcelPackage(fi)) {
    var currentSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets;
    var sheet = currentSheet.First();
    sheet.Row(sheet.Dimension.End.Row);
    sheet.Cells.LoadFromCollection(myData, true);

    package.SaveAs(fi);
}
```

Comment: Googling "c# epplus find last row" ought to be useful.

Comment: I did google, The code sheet.Row(sheet.Dimension.End.Row); takes it to the last row, The problem is not sure if LoadFromCollection can write from that row onwards, or some other call is needed

Comment: sheet.Cells[1, lastrow+1].LoadFromCollection(...